# Get attribute from array of $(this) selector

Tags: jquery, arrays, attributes, this

I have a jquery plugin that uploads the selected photo using ajax and php.

It works fine but i need to pass the attribute of the selected photo to php. I recieve the html element in `$(this)[0]`. I need something like:

```
$(this)[0].attr("data-index");
```

What is the proper way of getting `attr` from `$(this)[0]`

Comment: `$(this).eq(0).attr("data-index")` or `$($(this)[0]).attr("data-index");`

Comment: If you don't want to wrap the element again in jquery wrapper then you can use javascript approach `$(this)[0].getAttribute("data-index");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the element like

```
$($(this))
```

Then you can find the attribute

So your code should look like

```
$($(this)[0]).attr("data-index");
```

Comment: @webarch - This is needlessly inefficient.  `$(this).attr("data-index");` is all that is needed.  There's no need for the double nested jQuery objects or for the `[0]` here.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes. You are right. I thaught he was getting that from an array. I will update it

Comment: @RinoRaj i'm getting that from an array, so your first answer was correct

Comment: @WebArch Reverted back to old one.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can do this:

```
$(this).data("index");
```

which will automatically access the `data-index` attribute using jQuery's `.data()` feature.

Or you can use this to read the attribute directly:

```
$(this).attr("data-index");
```

Since, you know there's only one element in the jQuery object, there's no reason to use the `[0]` complication.  Though you don't need it here, if you ever want the first item out of a jQuery object and you want the result in a jQuery object, you can use `.eq(0)` as in `$(this).eq(0).attr("data-index");`, but since you already know there's only one element in `$(this)`, there's no reason for it here.

---

Or, in plain JS, you can do this:

```
this.getAttribute("data-index");
```

Or, in modern browsers, you can do:

```
this.dataset.index
```

which uses the newer [`.dataset` feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).